# courier authdaemon weird password handling

Tags: imap

Ok, so I have VERY weird problem with my courier installation.. When I try to log in, I need username and password right? Except that I can as password use any string, which has prefix same like my password. Example:

let say that this is my password:

```
#password#
```

I can successfully log in with ANY of the following passwords:

```
#password#
#password#FOO
#password#BAR
```

etc..

I am using mysql for storing user data, this is my /etc/courier/authmysqlrc

```
MYSQL_SERVER localhost
MYSQL_USERNAME #USER
MYSQL_PASSWORD #PASSWORD
MYSQL_PORT 0
MYSQL_DATABASE mail
MYSQL_USER_TABLE users
MYSQL_CRYPT_PWFIELD password
#MYSQL_CLEAR_PWFIELD password
MYSQL_UID_FIELD 5000
MYSQL_GID_FIELD 5000
MYSQL_LOGIN_FIELD email
MYSQL_HOME_FIELD "/home/vmail"
MYSQL_MAILDIR_FIELD CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1),'/')
#MYSQL_NAME_FIELD
MYSQL_QUOTA_FIELD quota
```

Where could be a problem? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the passwords are crypted by using the operating system's `crypt()` function, which looks only at the first 8 characters of the password to generate the encrypted hash.
As explained [here](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/134):

> If you have a password longer than 8 characters, as long as the first
>   8 characters match, crypt() will call it a valid match. For example,
>   if your password is “password” and is stored as a crypted hash in a
>   htpasswd file, checking against “passwordX” will be exactly the same
>   as checking against “password”, “password123″, and so on; that is, it
>   will be returned as a valid check because the first 8 characters match
>   properly. Similarly, if your password is “longpassword” and you check
>   against only “longpass”, that will be returned as valid, too.

Comment: thanks, did not know about that.. little scary :/ is there anything I can do about it? Like tell authdaemon to switch to another hashing function?

Comment: @Paladin Maybe you could try to use CRAM-MD5 authentication, since `authmysqlrc` supports it, as you can read [here](http://www.courier-mta.org/authlib/README.authmysql.html). You can find further informations about CRAM-MD5 authentication [here](http://www.inter7.com/courierimap/INSTALL.html#crammd5)

Comment: Yeah, I considered CRAM-MD5, but "CRAM-MD5 authentication is also be supported by authldap, authpgsql and authmysql, as long as clear-text passwords are used.".. I don't like clear text passwords..

Comment: Yeah, I think I will have to change courier-authlib to support md5 hashes... :/ all the rest of email-related thingies does support it.